# Can't Install Rails - Windows 8, Ruby 2.0.0p247

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails. I was trying to install it using [this guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-installation.htm), but I seem to be getting an error saying

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --include-dependencies
```

I'm running Windows 8, and my Ruby version is 2.0.0p247. If anyone could let me know what this is all about, how I can fix this, etc., that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You might try updating your gem install first with "gem update --system", then try your command again or you could just try "gem install rails" without the dependency option since it will install them anyways.

Comment: @tchester - now I'm getting an error asking me to update PATH to include build tools. What does that mean, and how do I do that?

Comment: I believe that you will need to download the "DevKit" add-on from the ruby installer site. I believe this URL also has directions that will help in that area: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Comment: If you do not have a preference on ruby and rails version you can download a packaged installer from http://railsinstaller.org/en which has ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2 as an alternative option.

Comment: @tchester - Alright, that works a lot better. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've been slowly building up my own, personal guide on how to get a descent development environment (including git, ruby, ruby devkit, and rails) up and running on Windows. I have used this on Windows 7, 8, and 10. It's time to finally post it somewhere.

This guide installs ruby 2.1.6 32-bit, even on 64-bit operating systems. It can likely be updated to ruby 2.2.2 but I have not tried it and therefore cannot claim it works. Also, not everything in this guide will apply to you or you may wish to switch out some components, e.g., Git for Windows vs. GitExtensions, but that's your call. This it what has worked for me without duplicating things such as multiple msys install locations.

**Overview of installed software & order**

- PuTTY 64-bit
- Java JRE 64-bit
- PostgreSQL 64-bit
- NodeJS 64-bit
- msysgit **32-bit**
- KDiff3 64-bit
- GitExtensions 64-bit
- ruby 2.1.6 **32-bit**
- ruby DevKit **32-bit**

**Installation instructions**

1. Install PuTTY (64-bit)

   - https://blog.splunk.net/64bit-putty/
   - Add path to PuTTY executables to your system Path variable
2. Install Java (64-bit), currently Version 8 Update 60

   - Full JDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
   - JRE only: http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp
3. Install PostgreSQL (64-bit)

   - http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows
   - **Run installer as Administrator**
   - Set Windows Service to run as Local System instead of Network Service (restart server before installing modules via Stack Builder)
   - **gem pg >= 0.18 supports ruby 2.1 on Windows**
4. Install Node.js (64-bit)

   - http://nodejs.org/download/
5. Download & install the latest version of msysgit

   - http://msysgit.github.io
   - Sadly, 32-bit only for now (this is why we're not doing ruby 64-bit as well)
6. Install it to C:\RubyDevKit\

   - Have the installer update the full Windows path (the option that warns about find.exe, etc.)
   - Choose Check out Windows, commit Unix line endings
   - Add C:\RubyDevKit\bin and C:\RubyDevKit\cmd to your system path
7. Install KDiff3 (64-bit)

   - http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/files/kdiff3/
8. Download & install GitExtensions

   - http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/
   - Don't install KDiff3 or Git, we already did that, so you can choose to download just the Setup.msi, not the Complete
   - After installation, inside GitExtensions settings, it might not know where Git is but it can fix itself (git should be in the path).
9. Download the ruby 2 installer

   - http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
   - Choose the 32-bit version because we want to keep everything the same & msysgit doesn't do 64-bit yet
   - (currently, Ruby 2.1.6) install to C:\Ruby21 (include in path, associate .rb files)
10. Extract the ruby DevKit to C:\RubyDevKit

    - Download the proper version for ruby 2.1 here: * https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit
    - I'm using: DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe
    - Don't overwrite files already installed by msysgit
11. Update your local path to something like:

`C:\Ruby21\bin;C:\RubyDevKit\bin;C:\RubyDevKit\mingw\bin;
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\;
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin`

12. Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save it to C:\RubyDevKit\ssl\certs

    - In Control Panel, add this to your environment:

`SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\RubyDevKit\ssl\certs\cacert.pem`

13. Open a Windows Command Prompt & follow the instructions further down on the DevKit install page.
14. Still in the Windows Command Prompt (may need to be Admin?), run: gem install rails

    - (this can take some time)
15. Finally, run: gem update rake

    - Choose yes when asked to overwrite rake in Ruby21/bin, this one is newer.

I hope this helps!

**What doesn't work?**

- therubyracer - which means:

  - use poltergeist (phantomjs) instead of capybara-webkit for testing
  - use bootstrap-sass instead of less-rails-bootstrap